# How to manipulate data.frame in the data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the `data.table` where some columns of observations contain `data.frame`. For example:

```
data.table(colA=   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
                  colB=list(data.frame(), 
                            data.frame(colsubB1=c('B2a','B2b'),colsubB2=c('B2c', 'B2d')), 
                            data.frame(colsubB1=c('A3a','A3b'),colsubB2=c('A3c', 'A3d'))),
                  colC=   c('C1','C2','C3'), 
                  colD=   c('D1','D2','D3')
                  )
```

return,

```
   colA         colB colC colD
1:   A1 <data.frame>   C1   D1
2:   A2 <data.frame>   C2   D2
3:   A3 <data.frame>   C3   D3
```

I expect the following result:

```
    colA colsubB1 colsubB2 colC colD
1:   A1     <NA>     <NA>   C1   D1
2:   A2      B2a      B2c   C2   D2
3:   A2      B2b      B2d   C2   D2
4:   A3      A3a      A3c   C3   D3
5:   A3      A3b      A3d   C3   D3
```

Could you please give some suggestion?

Comment: What you probably *should*  do is fix the code that creates your data.table. I wouldn't create a list column of data.frames.

Answer (score 3):

Using `by`:

```
DT[, if(nrow(colB[[1L]]) > 0) 
        colB[[1L]] 
    else 
        data.frame(colsubB1=NA_character_, colsubB2=NA_character_), 
    by=setdiff(names(DT), "colB")]
```

output:

```
   colA colC colD colsubB1 colsubB2
1:   A1   C1   D1     <NA>     <NA>
2:   A2   C2   D2      B2a      B2c
3:   A2   C2   D2      B2b      B2d
4:   A3   C3   D3      A3a      A3c
5:   A3   C3   D3      A3b      A3d
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(colA=   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
    colB=list(data.frame(), 
        data.frame(colsubB1=c('B2a','B2b'),colsubB2=c('B2c', 'B2d')), 
        data.frame(colsubB1=c('A3a','A3b'),colsubB2=c('A3c', 'A3d'))),
    colC=   c('C1','C2','C3'), 
    colD=   c('D1','D2','D3')
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
DT[, {
  lens  = sapply(colB, nrow)
  empty = data.table(colB[[which.max(lens > 0)]])[NA_integer_]
  unnested = rbindlist(replace(colB, lens == 0, list(empty)))
  repped   = .SD[rep(.I, pmax(lens, 1L))]

  # figure out column positions
  s = order(c(
    match(names(repped), names(DT)), 
    rep(match("colB", names(DT)), ncol(unnested))
  ))

  setcolorder(cbind(repped, unnested), s)
}, .SDcols=!"colB"]

   colA colsubB1 colsubB2 colC colD
1:   A1     <NA>     <NA>   C1   D1
2:   A2      B2a      B2c   C2   D2
3:   A2      B2b      B2d   C2   D2
4:   A3      A3a      A3c   C3   D3
5:   A3      A3b      A3d   C3   D3
```

If no elements of colB have any contents, desired output is unclear. I guess you should manually write in the value of `empty` as in @chinsoon's answer in that case, if it is known.

Comment: I could ask this in a separate question but maybe it's simple enough for you to answer here, do you know why my solution doesn't work if I remove the `which` ? Usually logical `i` indices seem to be handled smoothly.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Apparently it is deliberate, but I haven't thought about it or used it since I first read all the way through `?data.table` long ago. I think the inconsistency with base R doesn't buy much so posted a question/FR linking here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3699

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990956/data-table-has-unexpected-behavior-with-in-i-when-using-list-columns

Answer (score 1):

you can actually use `tidyr::unnest()` :

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
# data edited to avoid warnings
DT <- data.table(colA=   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
           colB=list(data.frame(row.names = 1), 
                     data.frame(colsubB1=c('B2a','B2b'),colsubB2=c('B2c', 'B2d'),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
                     data.frame(colsubB1=c('A3a','A3b'),colsubB2=c('A3c', 'A3d'),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),
           colC=   c('C1','C2','C3'), 
           colD=   c('D1','D2','D3')
)
# with current version of tidyr, unnest can remove rows, should be fixed in next
# version, but for now we need to add a row to our empty data.frames
# no idea why the which was needed
DT[which(!lengths(colB)), colB := list(list(data.frame(row.names = 1)))]
# then just unnest
DT[, unnest(.SD,colB)]
#>    colA colC colD colsubB1 colsubB2
#> 1:   A1   C1   D1     <NA>     <NA>
#> 2:   A2   C2   D2      B2a      B2c
#> 3:   A2   C2   D2      B2b      B2d
#> 4:   A3   C3   D3      A3a      A3c
#> 5:   A3   C3   D3      A3b      A3d
# or 
unnest(DT, colB)
#>    colA colC colD colsubB1 colsubB2
#> 1:   A1   C1   D1     <NA>     <NA>
#> 2:   A2   C2   D2      B2a      B2c
#> 3:   A2   C2   D2      B2b      B2d
#> 4:   A3   C3   D3      A3a      A3c
#> 5:   A3   C3   D3      A3b      A3d
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe remove which but keep the brackets

Comment: iirc there is a faq on this regarding logical i. I suspect that it interprets the ! first when parsing the code. But most likely my knowledge is skimpy. Best to wait for The experts to answer

Comment: didn't find it , if I do `L <- lengths(DT$colB)` followed by `DT[!L, colB := list(list(data.frame(row.names = 1)))]` it works, seems like a bug but it doesnt feel like I did anything fancy. I'll file an issue if I don't get the explanation here

Comment: it returns `[1] 0 2 2`

Comment: I'll ask a separate question here when I get the time to figure out a minimum working example, then file an issue if it's unexpected behavior.

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990956/data-table-has-unexpected-behavior-with-in-i-when-using-list-columns