# data.table has unexpected behavior with `!` in `i` when using list columns

Tags: r, data.table

See the following example:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = list(character(), "bar", "baz"))
DT[]
#>    x   y
#> 1: 1    
#> 2: 2 bar
#> 3: 3 baz
!lengths(DT$y)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

# this is wrong:
DT[!lengths(y), ]
#>    x   y
#> 1: 2 bar
#> 2: 3 baz

# but this is right (adding brackets):
DT[(!lengths(y)), ]
#>    x y
#> 1: 1

DT2 <- copy(DT)
# this is wrong
DT[!lengths(y), y:= list(list("foo"))][]
#>    x   y
#> 1: 1    
#> 2: 2 foo
#> 3: 3 foo

# but this is right (adding brackets):
DT2[(!lengths(y)), y:= list(list("foo"))][]
#>    x   y
#> 1: 1 foo
#> 2: 2 bar
#> 3: 3 baz
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is this a bug or does `!` have a special role in `i` in *data.table* ?

*related to [How to manipulate data.frame in the data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981960/how-to-manipulate-data-frame-in-the-data-table/56986529?noredirect=1#comment100515368_56986529)*

Comment: Set `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)`. You pass integers (row numbers) and data.table does a not-join. `DT[!as.logical(lengths(y)), ]` gives the expected result.

Comment: could you share your error message? at a glance it's a bug, please file. relatedly (1) yes, ! has special meaning -- it's the anti-join operator in i. (2) I suspect your query is being interpreted as a join (though I think? the (y) part should negate this); verbose = TRUE might clear this up. hence wrapping in () to force evaluation as logical (not as potential join key) or explicitly setting ==TRUE work

Comment: @Michael there is no error message, this is all I get, all the more dangerous :). I'll file the issue ASAP.

Comment: There is no issue to report. There is no way to support your intended result and keep the syntax for anti-joins. This is a user error. You need to be more strict with types and type conversions within data.table than in base R.

Comment: help on `i` says "integer and logical vectors work the same way they do in [.data.frame except logical NAs are treated as FALSE.". This is not what we get here so I believe doc should at least warn the user, this syntax is only documented in the examples as far as I can see, so hard to debug.

Comment: and why couldn't `[.data.table` check that `!` is applied on a data.frame ? what is the use of applying to integers ?

Comment: The problem is you don't pass a logical vector.  The documentation says "i prefixed with ! signals a not-join or not-select." But sure, create a pull-request with clarified documentation ...

Comment: I can't find your quote on the help page.

Comment: The use is `DT[!c(100, 200)]` gives you everything except these rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196328/discussion-between-moody-mudskipper-and-roland).

Comment: It's in `help("data.table")`.

Comment: It seems to me the ability to use `!` with integers is of no value because you can already use `-` for that. I guess at this point it may be a question of whether other packages have come to depend on this functionality though.