# How can I bind a list of values of a data.table column as extra rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have an R data.table related question. In my table, one column ('b') can contain several values. For every comma-separated value I would like to have an extra row in the data table with the value of column 'a' next to it.

```
# begin format data
d= data.table(a=c(1:3), b = c('a','b','c,d'))
# end format data
d2= data.table(a=c(1:3,3), b = c('a','b','c','d'))
```

I have started separating column b and store it as a list, but could not figure out how to get the final end format data.

```
d[,b2:= strsplit(b, ",")]
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately this is really a dupe of [How to manipulate data.frame in the data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56981960/3358272), though informed by https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2146 and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3672.

Long-story-short, the generic "right way" is likely

```r
tidyr::unnest(d[, b := strsplit(b, ",")], b)
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#       a b    
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 a    
# 2     2 b    
# 3     3 c    
# 4     3 d
```

though you can work around it with *this* data with

```r
d[, b := strsplit(b, ",")
  ][, setnames(do.call(data.frame, .SD), names(d)), by = seq_len(nrow(d))
  ][,-1]
#        a      b
#    <int> <char>
# 1:     1      a
# 2:     2      b
# 3:     3      c
# 4:     3      d
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your quick response. Didn't find this issue, but it works for my case (both solutions). Thanks.